# Split dataframe into smaller dataframes based on range of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
     x     text     
1    500   aa
2    550   bb
3    700   cc
4    750   dd
```

My goal is to split this df if the x-values are more than 100 points apart.

Is there a pandas function that allows you to make a split based on range of values?

Here is my desired output:

df_1:

```
    x     text  
0   500   aa
1   550   bb
```

df_2:

```
    x     text  
0   700   cc
1   750   dd
```

Comment: Are your ranges *dynamic* or just separated by 100 at all times? To be specific, should `[400, 450, 500, 550]` be in same dataframe?

Comment: @RockyLi dynamic

Comment: @RockyLi yes, that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need convert groupby object to tuple and dictionary by helper `Series`:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['x'].diff().gt(100).cumsum())))
print (d)
{0:      x text
1  500   aa
2  550   bb, 1:      x text
3  700   cc
4  750   dd}
```

**Detail**:

First get difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), compare by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater and create consecutive groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print (df['x'].diff().gt(100).cumsum())
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
Name: x, dtype: int32
```

Comment: How do I account for a range between -130 and 130? In other words, anything greater than 130 or less than -130

Comment: @Sam - Not tested,but how working `df['x'].diff().gt(100).cumsum()` chnaged to `df['x'].diff().abs().gt(130).cumsum()` ?

Comment: @Sam - do you think filter by `df[df['x'].between(-130, 130)]` ?

Answer (score 0):

make a new column with shift(1) and then separate by the difference between the values of these columns